# Javascript - How to filter custom repetitive objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Based on an objects array like this. I want to filter repetitive objects key, in order to affect some repetitive keys but not everyone.

```
var arr = [
    {id: 1, value: 'John'},
    {id: 2, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 3, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 4, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 5, value: 'Alex'},
    {id: 6, value: 'Louis'},
    {id: 7, value: 'David'},
    {id: 8, value: 'David'}, // Should not be filtered

]
```

Result:

```
arr = [
    {id: 1, value: 'John'},
    {id: 5, value: 'Alex'},
    {id: 6, value: 'Louis'},
    {id: 7, value: 'David'},
    {id: 8, value: 'David'},

]
```

I tried this at the moment:

```
arr = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    if (!a.some(x => x.description === b.description)) a.push(b);
    return a;
}, []);
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with?

Comment: you tried anything ?

Comment: why not `id: 8`?

Comment: There's no `description` property in your objects, how could the code you tried work?

Answer (score 2):

If you like to filter duplicates and keep the first object, you could take a closure over a `Set` for filtering.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, value: 'John' }, { id: 2, value: 'John' }, { id: 3, value: 'John' }, { id: 4, value: 'John' }, { id: 5, value: 'Alex' }, { id: 6, value: 'Louis' }, { id: 7, value: 'David' }, { id: 8, value: 'David' }],
    keep = ['David'],
    result = array.filter(
        (s => ({ value }) => keep.includes(value) || !s.has(value) && s.add(value))
        (new Set)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like your solution with closure. too complicated for beginners but is nice. :)

Comment: it is so nice.:) thanks, building regex is quite expensive. so i use it like that. 
.filter(((regex) => str => !regex.test(str))(/^(\s|[,])*$/))

Answer (score 1):

Just uising [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Set) data structure, and some array or set with exceptions.

```js
var arr = [
    {id: 1, value: 'John'},
    {id: 2, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 3, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 4, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 5, value: 'Alex'},
    {id: 6, value: 'Louis'},
    {id: 7, value: 'David'},
    {id: 8, value: 'David'}, // Should not be filtered

]

const filterDuplicates = (arr, exceptions) => {
  const values = new Set();
  return arr.filter(item => {
    if(values.has(item.value) && !exceptions.includes(item.value)){
      return false;
    } else {
      values.add(item.value);
      return true;
    }
  })
}

console.log(filterDuplicates(arr, ["David"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#filter` with a boolean flag to store whether or not the value has already appeared.

```js
var arr = [
    {id: 1, value: 'John'},
    {id: 2, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 3, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 4, value: 'John'}, // Should be filtered
    {id: 5, value: 'Alex'},
    {id: 6, value: 'Louis'},
    {id: 7, value: 'David'},
    {id: 8, value: 'David'}, // Should not be filtered
];
const removeRepeats = (arr, val)=>{
  let found = false;
  return arr.filter(({value})=>value !== val || (!found && (found = true)));
};
console.log(removeRepeats(arr, 'John'));
```

Comment: The `found` variable makes this only remove the first set of duplicates, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 1, value: "John" },
  { id: 2, value: "John" }, // Should be filtered
  { id: 3, value: "John" }, // Should be filtered
  { id: 4, value: "John" }, // Should be filtered
  { id: 5, value: "Alex" },
  { id: 6, value: "Louis" },
  { id: 7, value: "David" },
  { id: 8, value: "David" }, // Should not be filtered
];

const filtered = Array.from(
  arr
    .reduce((filtered, item) => {
      if (!filtered.has(item.value)) {
        filtered.set(item.value, item);
      }
      return filtered;
    }, new Map())
    .values()
);

console.log(filtered);
```